# Why MS Access Form in Datasheet view stops responding to requery command after removing filters on fields?

Tags: ms-access, office365

I have an ms Access form that is linked to query.

The query depends on a control on another form to filter the data

I set the view of the form to be Data Sheet View to have the capabilities of filtering and sorting.

The form at start responds to the Requery command correctly.

When filter is applied to the data it keeps responding to the Requery command

When the filter is removed it stops responding to the Requery command. Command is executed normally without any error but displayed data doesn't respond to the change.

I run the underlying query at the same time and it responds well.

When applying any filter again the response returns to normal again

Do any one have a clue about this problem?

I am using Ms Access 2019 64bit (integrated with Office 365 package)

Here is sample database link to clarify the problem. Run frmMain and follow the steps on the right to replicate the problem

[DemoDB](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18dIdCKvBhfQlD-aAlFAYHtY_0mOeAsKx/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody dropping here I had an answer from Microsoft Community as follows (related to shared demo sample):

Change the code for the button Check8 to:

```
Private Sub Check8_Click() 
    If Me.frmSubSub.Form.Filter = "" Then 
        frmSubSub.Form.RecordSource = frmSubSub.Form.RecordSource 
    Else 
        frmSubSub.Form.Requery 
    End If 
End Sub
```

This worked fine for me despite the demo shows there is a bug in MsAccess to deal with this situation.
Link to question on MS Community: [Link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/ms-access-form-in-datasheet-view-stops-responding/12b45598-d494-4547-b1ce-7b03ce9a3c8f)